# Diferença entre tuple e set

Tags: python, set, atributos, tuple

Estou trabalhando com python e fiquei na dúvida qual seria a diferença entre um set(set()) e um tuple(tuple()). Sei que ambos se delimitam com '()'.

Mas tentei atribuir um atributo set a um tuple, ou seja:

ESTE É O MEU SET: (OU O QUE EU PENSAVA QUE ERA...)

```
basket = ('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'pear')
```

DEI O SEGUINTE COMANDO:

```
basket.discard(2))
print (basket)
```

Quando corri o programa deu erro...Dizia:

*line 16: basket.discard(2)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'discard'*

**Porque considerou o meu set como um tuple?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque para python os parênteses delimitam uma tupla, e não um conjunto. Se você quiser um `set`, você precisa usar as chaves (`{`, `}`) ou a função `set`:

```
basket = {'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'pear'}
```

ou

```
basket = set(('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'pear'))
```

Comment: Mas se eu usar '{}' encara como dictionary, em python 3.5.0

Comment: Sim, para criar um set vazio você não pode usar `{}` (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Se isso é uma possibilidade, então você pode sempre usar a função `set`.

Comment: Então, quando é que eu posso utilizar {} para criar um set (que não seja vazio claro)?

Comment: Se você usar algo do tipo `{1, 2, 3}` ou `{'apple', 'banana', 'orange'}` você vai ter `set`s. Se você usar a sintaxe de dicionário (`{'apple': 'banana', 'orange': 'pineapple'}`) é que você terá um dicionário.